# how can we reduce the temperature below -60 degree celsius?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics, thermodynamics

To reduce the temperature below -60 degree celsius. we have to do a project based on this subject.

Comment: Sounds like dry ice (frozen $CO_2$) will do.

Comment: As @CuriousOne said, dry ice would probably do, you can get it with ease too, A lot of ice-cream makers in India use dry ice to keep their ice-creams cool :)

Answer (score 0):

From your name, I'd guess that you are located in India, and in that case I can't help you. In the US, the obvious way is to get some liquid nitrogen. Currently, prices run USD.10 to USD.20/liter. If you are associated with a university with a physics department, you may be able to find a source within your school. LN2 boils at 77 K.

Comment: LN2 also requires a dewar to handle... dry ice can be transported in a plastic bag.

Comment: Considering I play tennis with 15 Indian immigrants, your guess may be wrong :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - Absolutely true, but I was playing the odds.